# Update insert WFS in GeoServer with same template

Tags: geoserver, wfs-t

With Python I'm adding new points to a GeoServer layer via WFS REST like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:Transaction xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:ws="http://www.ws.org/" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs">
   <wfs:Insert>
      <ws:full>
         <ws:name>Munic</ws:name>
         <ws:uuid>abc01</ws:uuid>
         <ws:the_geom>
            <gml:Point srsDimension="2" srsName="EPSG:4326">
               <gml:pos>11.3154296875 52.522905940278065</gml:pos>
            </gml:Point>
         </ws:the_geom>
      </ws:full>
   </wfs:Insert>
</wfs:Transaction>
```

However when I try to update them I get a null pointer exception

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wfs:Transaction xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:ws="http://www.ws.org/" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" service="WFS" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs">
   <wfs:Update>
      <ws:full>
         <ws:name>Berlin</ws:name>
         <ws:the_geom>
            <gml:Point srsDimension="2" srsName="EPSG:4326">
               <gml:pos>13.3154296875 52.522905940278065</gml:pos>
            </gml:Point>
         </ws:the_geom>
         <ogc:Filter>
             <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                 <ogc:PropertyName>uuid</ogc:PropertyName>
                 <ogc:Literal>abc01</ogc:Literal>
             </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
         </ogc:Filter>
      </ws:full>
   </wfs:Update>
</wfs:Transaction>
```

It looks like something is not correct with the update schema or the Filter which selects the point in question. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you are using `insert` to try to do an `update` but to be sure you need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: sorry my bad. corrected it. Still the same wrong null pointer exception. Does the ogc Filter look correct for you in this scheme?

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: The response stays the same after setting more verbose logging. Same null pinter. https://hastebin.com/efabeqopak.xml I will consult the official schema definition again. I have the feeling something is wrong with my update template.

Comment: Okay I think I have it for update it's working when the layername is set as attribute <wfs:Update typeName="{layerName}">`

Comment: @IanTurton can you tell why this post is not suitable for this site so that I can do better in future? After reading the docs I now see that my update scheme is wrong and should look like: https://hastebin.com/ujikosiyoh.xml This answer could have helped others in future as well?

Comment: You said it was a typo - if it is more then post an answer

Answer (score 0):

After going through geoserver docs again it looks like the needed insert and upload scheme differ. In other words it's not possible to use xml nodes like

```
   <wfs:Insert>
      <ws:full>

   <wfs:Update>
      <ws:full>
```

Following works:

## insert

```
<wfs:Transaction service="WFS" version="1.0.0"
 ......>
 <wfs:Insert>
 <topp:tasmania_roads>
 <topp:the_geom>
 <gml:MultiLineString
srsName="http://www.opengis.net/gml/srs/epsg.xml#4326">
 <gml:lineStringMember>
 <gml:LineString>
 <gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">
494475.71056415,5433016.8189323 494982.70115662,5435041.95096618
 </gml:coordinates>
 </gml:LineString>
 </gml:lineStringMember>
 </gml:MultiLineString>
 </topp:the_geom>
 <topp:TYPE>alley</topp:TYPE>
 </topp:tasmania_roads>
 </wfs:Insert>
</wfs:Transaction>

# update

<wfs:Transaction service="WFS" version="1.0.0"
  xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp"
  xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs">
  <wfs:Update typeName="topp:tasmania_roads">
    <wfs:Property>
      <wfs:Name>TYPE</wfs:Name>
      <wfs:Value>street</wfs:Value>
    </wfs:Property>
    <ogc:Filter>
      <ogc:FeatureId fid="tasmania_roads.1"/>
    </ogc:Filter>
  </wfs:Update>
</wfs:Transaction>
```